# calculate linear combinations of areas

Tags: calculus

it seems very easy or maybe easiest,but i want to make sure that i am not missing anything,that why let us consider following  problem
[image]

clearly it would be  $25/9+ln9=25/9+2*ln3$   is it so simply ?thanks in advance,sorry  for such question,but i like to make sure in everything,that's why i have posted it  here

Comment: Not everything is hard.  Just most things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is that simple. Your procedure is correct.